# Instead of updating the tkinter gui, it adds a new one to the table

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am developing an application. The application needs to adjust itself every 1 second as new data comes in. but the application creates a new image downwards instead of editing the image.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
import time
root = Tk()
lab = Label(root)
lab.pack()



def main():
 y = randint(0,1000)
 root.after(1000, main) # run itself again after 1000 ms

 #random.randint(0, 250)
 x= 250
 print(y)
 
 root.geometry("250x250")

 canvas = Canvas()
 canvas.create_line(0, y/2, x, y/2 ,  width=2 , fill="#ffffff") # Çizgi
 canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 250, y/2-1,
 outline="#0000CD", fill="#0000CD")# RENK
 canvas.create_rectangle(0, 250, 250, y/2+1,
 outline="#734a12", fill="#734a12") #RENK
    #ara çizgiler
 canvas.create_line(100, 145, 150, 145 ,  width=2 , fill="#ffffff")
 canvas.create_line(110, 165, 140,  165,  width=2 , fill="#ffffff")
 canvas.create_line(100, 185, 150, 185 ,  width=2 , fill="#ffffff")
 canvas.create_line(110, 205, 140,  205,  width=2 , fill="#ffffff")
 canvas.create_line(100, 225, 150, 225 ,  width=2 , fill="#ffffff")
 canvas.create_line(110, 245, 140,  245,  width=2 , fill="#ffffff")

 canvas.create_line(100, 105, 150, 105 ,  width=2 , fill="#ffffff")
 canvas.create_line(110, 85, 140,  85,  width=2 , fill="#ffffff")
 canvas.create_line(100, 65, 150, 65 ,  width=2 , fill="#ffffff")
 canvas.create_line(110, 45, 140,  45,  width=2 , fill="#ffffff")
 canvas.create_line(100, 25, 150, 25 ,  width=2 , fill="#ffffff")
 canvas.create_line(110, 5, 140,  5,  width=2 , fill="#ffffff")
 canvas.create_line(90, 125, 170, 125, fill="#ffff00" ,  width=3  ,dash=(4, 2))
  
   




  canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
 main()

 root.mainloop()
```

[image]

I want to have only one of these but that's how it works, thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling it to create something new every second. Move the code that updates the window to a separate function from the code that creates the widgets. Call `main` once, then call this other function every second.